# Java - generics & wildcards & interface versus implementation

Tags: java, generics

I have a question about Java generics. Say I have the following interface:

```
public static class Something<T> {
    public void set(T t) {
    }
}

public static interface Manager<T> {
    public void add(final String key, final Something<T> o);

    public Something<T> get(final String key);
}
```

An example of usage:

```
final Manager<Number> m = ...;

m.add("key", new Something<Number>());
m.get("key").set(new Integer(5));
```

I would also like to be able to add `Something<Integer>`, `Something<Double>`, ... to the a `Manager<Number>`. I would say I have to change the signature of the add-function:

```
public static interface Manager<T> {
    public void add(final String key, final Something<? extends T> o);

    public Something<T> get(final String key);
}

final Manager<Number> m = ...;

m.add("key", new Something<Integer>());
m.get("key").set(new Integer(5));
```

So far, so good. Let's look at a possible implementation of the manager:

```
public static class ManagerImplementation<T> implements Manager<T> {
    protected HashMap<String, Something<T>> map = new HashMap<String, Something<T>>();

    public void add(final String key, final Something<? extends T> o) {
        map.put(key, o); // <--- here
    }

    public Something<T> get(final String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

This fails, since you cannot add a `Something<? extends T>` to a `Map<X, Something<T>>`. So let's change this:

```
public static class ManagerImplementation<T> implements Manager<T> {
    protected HashMap<String, Something<? extends T>> map = new HashMap<String, Something<? extends T>>();

    public void add(final String key, final Something<? extends T> o) {
        map.put(key, o);
    }

    public Something<T> get(final String key) {
        return map.get(key); // <--- here
    }
}
```

This fails since `map.get(key)` returns `Something<? extends T>` while the get-function is required to return `Something<T>`, as defined in the interface.

What is the common approach to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you change the get method in the interface to `public Something<? extends T> get(final String key);` as well?

Comment: @HariShankar this will return `Something<? extends T>` so OP will not be able to `set` anything via such reference (except `null`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your class you are always using `Something<? extends T>`, thus in your `public get` method you must convert the inside world to the outside world format. E.g. you can simply cast the result of `map.get(key)` to `Something<T>`:

```
return (Something<T>) map.get(key); // <--- here
```

Comment: I am fairly new to generics. I have always had the idea that you can avoid casts when generics are in place. So this is not true? This can only be solved correctly by using a cast?

Comment: From a practical point of view my advice is: Use generics, but use them sparsely. Usually one degree of generics (like '<V>', no extends or super) is enough, everything more is overcomplicated and makes your code unreadable. With an emphasis on 'usually'. ;-)

Comment: So, in other words, you are saying that for the outside world/API, the generics must be as expected (with wildcards if necessary), but for the implementation, it is best to keep it as simple as possible?

Comment: It's a bit of philosophical question, but I'd keep generics *always* as simple as possible (of course they have to satisfy the design as well as 3rd party APIs). Seen too many classes with lots of undocumented (!) generics, which no programmer wanted to use.